# Value initialization from signed char to integer, premature promotion?

Tags: c++, integer-promotion, value-initialization

In this piece of code:

```
signed char v = -64;
int n = 4;
int x = v - '0' * (signed char)n;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Should `x` be `-5` or `-261`? In my understanding, the initializer expression has `signed char` type, and the type conversion should happen later, once the initializer has been calculated.

So, `v - '0' * (signed char)n` should be equal to `-5` because that's the equivalent value of `-261` in `signed char` valuation.

However, that piece of code prints `-261`.

Comment: [INT02-C. Understand integer conversion rules](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char`s and `short`s are promoted to `int` when doing arithmetic. The `(signed char)n` cast doesn't help since the result is immediately promoted right back up to `int` for the multiplication.

Here are the implicit conversions made explicit:

```
int x = (int)v - (int)'0' * (int)(signed char)n;
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression `v - '0' * (signed char)n` is grouped as `v - ('0' * (signed char)n)`

Both arguments `'0'` **and** `(signed char)n` are converted to `int` types prior to the multiplication. There is nothing you can do to stop that.

That total is subtracted from `v` which is also promoted to an `int`.

This yields `-261` on a platform with ASCII encoding.